# Progressive Web App: skipWaiting() with multiple service worker versions

Tags: progressive-web-apps

[**CONTEXT**]
I worked through [Jake Archibald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123395/jaffathecake)'s fantastic Udacity course found here: [Offline Web Applications](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud899).  His work provides a Toasts dialog alerting the user that there is an update available, and they are invited to update:

[Refresh / Dismiss Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECrgX.png)

While this dialog is available to the user, there's a **corner case** on hand that I can't seem to resolve:

***The service-worker can be updated any number of times prior to the client updating the local instance, pushing the numbered version of the service worker past 'just one more'.***  For example, the current and active service worker is #821, while the service worker that is waiting is now #824

[active and waiting service workers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiiY0.png)

[**PROBLEM**]
I cannot find the right way to alert the browser that the next service worker to install needs to be #824, instead of #822, the dialog-box + PWA tell me that the current browser is 'redundant', and that I can't get to service-worker #824 without refreshing, and then clicking the update button.

I can recreate this with any version of Jake's code once the service-worker is set, and skipWaiting() is introduced.

I literally just want to be able to cover the corner case where the service-worker is updated 2 or more times before the user decides to update their local PWA.

You can find Jake's code on github:  [Jakearchibald/wittr](https://github.com/jakearchibald/wittr/tree/master)

[**ASK**]: Has anyone found a solution for this corner case?  If so, how do you solve it?  What I'm seeing doesn't make sense as the service-worker lifecycle seems to respected per Googles documentation:  [service-workers/lifecyle](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

I did quite a bit of additional reading/research and found the following discussion threads on Github:
- [Provide an easier way to listen for waiting/activated/redundant Service Workers](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1247)
- [Immediate Service Worker](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1389)
- [Recommended Approach for Refreshing Page on new SW](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1120) 
- [Provide a one-line way to listen for a waiting Service Worker](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1222)

It looks like this idea was brought up in 2017, and has for the most part gone stale.  However, you can double down on using

`navigator.serviceWorker.waiting.then(reg => {
  if (confirm('refresh now?')) reg.waiting.postMessage('skipWaiting');
});`

That will give you the ability to listen for a new Web Worker, after activating Web Worker #1, then setting Web Worker #2 to redundant, and moving Web Worker #3 into a waiting state.  It's obtuse and indirect, but at least you can now move the 3# thread up and into the right slot.

A real shout-out to [dfabulich](https://github.com/dfabulich), [Matt Gaunt](https://github.com/gauntface), and [Beatrix Perez](https://github.com/beatrizdemiguelperez)